# Apache Camel parallelProcessing() equivalent threads() instruction

Tags: parallel-processing, apache-camel, threadpool

I'm trying to refactor some Apache Camel routes and optimize them as best as I can, without changing their general behavior. One thing I've seen is that most of this routes use the instruction `parallelProcessing()`.

Is there any way I can change this into a `threads()` without changing the behavior of the route?

I'd like to do that in order to limit the ThreadPool size. I've been told that the first instruction should be equivalent to `threads(30)` or something like that. Is this true? I haven't found anything about this on Google.

I'm using Java DSL.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Thread Pool profile and create a Custom Thread Pool.

Read more about this in the Camel docs: http://camel.apache.org/threading-model.html